# User Authentication in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Having problems authenticating and logging in users in Laravel 4.

My login form directs to this route.

```
Route::post('login', function() {
    // get POST data
    $userdata = array(
        'username'      => Input::get('username'),
        'password'      => Input::get('password')
    );

    if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) )
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to home
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    else
    {
        // auth failure! lets go back to the login
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->with('login_errors', true);
        // pass any error notification you want
        // i like to do it this way :)
    }
});
```

At this point everything seems to be going fine. I'm redirected to the home page just fine however, there is no user object stored. If I try to access any user function I get the "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Here is my User Model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tblusers';
    /**
     * The database key used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $key = 'userid';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function roles() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }

    public function permissions() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Permission');
    }

    public function hasRole($key) 
    {
        foreach($this->roles as $role){
            if($role->name === $key)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

A Piece of information i find strange. If, instead of redirecting to '/' I `return View::make('home')` it stores the object just fine, however when I leave that page it disappears again.

EDIT:

Since this must have something to do with sessions I've posted my session.php file for reference.

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "native", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'native',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle for it is expired. If you want them
    | to immediately expire when the browser closes, set it to zero.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 5,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the database
    | connection that should be used to manage your sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your "database" configuration file.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Payload Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "cookie" session driver, you may configure the name of
    | the cookie used as the session "payload". This cookie actually has
    | the encrypted session data stored within it for the application.
    |
    */

    'payload' => 'laravel_payload',

);
```

So far I've tried 'cookie' and 'native' session drivers each with no luck.

Comment: Share the code you're using to access your user, please.

Comment: Do you have setup your sessions correctly?

Comment: Using Native Session Driver

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro First time using Laravel, what exactly are you referring to? From the Docs I understood `Auth::attempt` to automatically interface with the user model and store the user in session. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: After that you need to use Auth::user() to access your logged user, is that what you're doing? I.e.: `Auth::user()->email`

Comment: Correct My "home" page looks like this right now. `<h1>Hello World!</h1>

{{Auth::user()->email;}}` And I get the non object error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Fix. In my model I had defined

`protected $key = 'userid'`

What I needed to do was change it to

`protected $primaryKey = 'userid';`

Hopefully this helps someone along the line.